# How does a class call methods after instantiating another class?

Tags: java, methods, getter-setter

I am very new to this community. I have tried to get up to speed on all rules before posting this question (as well as researching solutions). I apologize if I offended or broke any rules through ignorance. Please also excuse my awful code, I am still learning. Thank you for understanding!

EDIT: I have added additional information and tried different approaches to this issue I'm having. I have reworked part of the code below.

I am building a simple football game with a game field panel and control panel. The game field displays all of the player and tackles on the GUI. The control panel sets the difficulty of the game, starts the timer, and the type of quarterback. I ran into a road block where I have all of my code to compile correctly, but when calling set methods on the GameField class to update the score, it updates the variable but not the actual score through my JTextArea Score keeper.

I have instantiated the ControlPanel within the GameField class. I've also tested with a System.out.println() and it shows that it is indeed updating the variable. Is updating JTextArea allowed between classes?

**GameField.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GameField extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

ControlPanel cp = new ControlPanel();

// Game pieces
private JButton playerIcon = new JButton("RB");
private JButton tackleIcon1 = new JButton("LB");
private JButton tackleIcon2 = new JButton("LB");
private JButton fieldGoal = new JButton("FG");

// Player and Tackle locations
private int playerPositionX = 100;
private int playerPositionY = 500;
private int tackle1PositionX = 1200;
private int tackle1PositionY = 400;
private int tackle2PositionX = 1200;
private int tackle2PositionY = 600;

// Player variable speeds
private int playerSpeed = 20;

public GameField() {
    setLayout(null);
    setBackground(Color.green);

    add(playerIcon);
    playerIcon.setBounds(new Rectangle(getPlayerPositionX(), getPlayerPositionY(), 80, 30));
    add(tackleIcon1);
    tackleIcon1.setBounds(new Rectangle(getTackle1PositionX(), getTackle1PositionY(), 100, 50));
    add(tackleIcon2);
    tackleIcon2.setBounds(new Rectangle(getTackle2PositionX(), getTackle2PositionY(), 100, 50));
    add(fieldGoal);
    fieldGoal.setBounds(new Rectangle(1600, 100, 100, 800));
    playerIsTackled();
    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);

}

public void playerIsTackled() {
    Rectangle playerRect = playerIcon.getBounds();
    Rectangle tackle1Rect = tackleIcon1.getBounds();
    Rectangle tackle2Rect = tackleIcon2.getBounds();
    if (playerRect.intersects(tackle1Rect) || playerRect.intersects(tackle2Rect)) {
        setPlayerPositionX(100);
        setPlayerPositionY(500);
        setTackle1PositionX(1200);
        setTackle1PositionY(400);
        setTackle2PositionX(1200);
        setTackle2PositionY(600);
        playerIcon.setBounds(getPlayerPositionX(), getPlayerPositionY(), 80, 30);
        tackleIcon1.setBounds(getTackle1PositionX(), getTackle1PositionY(), 100, 50);
        tackleIcon2.setBounds(getTackle2PositionX(), getTackle2PositionY(), 100, 50);

        cp.setCurrentTackles(cp.getCurrentTackles() + 1);
        System.out.println(cp.getCurrentTackles());
    }
}

public void playerScored() {
    Rectangle playerRect = playerIcon.getBounds();
    Rectangle fieldGoalRect = fieldGoal.getBounds();
    if (playerRect.intersects(fieldGoalRect)) {
        setPlayerPositionX(100);
        setPlayerPositionY(500);
        setTackle1PositionX(1200);
        setTackle1PositionY(400);
        setTackle2PositionX(1200);
        setTackle2PositionY(600);
        playerIcon.setBounds(getPlayerPositionX(), getPlayerPositionY(), 80, 30);
        tackleIcon1.setBounds(getTackle1PositionX(), getTackle1PositionY(), 100, 50);
        tackleIcon2.setBounds(getTackle2PositionX(), getTackle2PositionY(), 100, 50);

        cp.setCurrentScore(cp.getCurrentScore() + 1);
        System.out.println(cp.getCurrentScore());
    }
} 

public void moveToPlayer() {      
    if (getTackle1PositionX() > getPlayerPositionX()) {
        setTackle1PositionX(getTackle1PositionX() - 1);
    } else {
        setTackle1PositionX(getTackle1PositionX() + 1);
    }

    if (getTackle1PositionY() > getPlayerPositionY()) {
        setTackle1PositionY(getTackle1PositionY() - 1);
    } else {
        setTackle1PositionY(getTackle1PositionY() + 1);
    }
    getTackleIcon1().setBounds(getTackle1PositionX(), getTackle1PositionY(), 100, 50);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    requestFocusInWindow();
    playerIsTackled();
    playerScored();
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int k = e.getKeyCode();
    if (k == e.VK_LEFT && getPlayerPositionX() > 0) {
        setPlayerPositionX(getPlayerPositionX() - getPlayerSpeed());
    }
    if (k == e.VK_RIGHT && getPlayerPositionX() < 1703) {
        setPlayerPositionX(getPlayerPositionX() + getPlayerSpeed());
    }
    if (k == e.VK_UP && getPlayerPositionY() > 0) {
        setPlayerPositionY(getPlayerPositionY() - getPlayerSpeed());
    }
    if (k == e.VK_DOWN && getPlayerPositionY() < 1089) {
        setPlayerPositionY(getPlayerPositionY() + getPlayerSpeed());
    }
    getPlayerIcon().setBounds(getPlayerPositionX(), getPlayerPositionY(), 80, 30);
}
```

Below is the **ControlPanel.java**. In the actionPerformed method, you can see I added a getScore().setText() method for updating the score. It correctly updates the score there if I replace the getCurrentScore() method with any integer.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class ControlPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, ChangeListener {

private JButton start;
private JButton stop;
private JSlider speed;
private JComboBox playerList;
private Timer tim;
private int delay = 1000;
private int i = 0;
private int currentScore = 0;
private int currentTackles = 0;
private JTextArea timer = new JTextArea("Timer: " + 0, 1, 6);
private JTextArea score = new JTextArea("Field Goals: " + currentScore + "       Tackles: " + currentTackles, 1, 16);
private String[] playerStyle = {"Slow Runner", "Running Back", "All Star"};

public ControlPanel() {

    super();
    setBackground(Color.darkGray);

    // Game controls
    start = new JButton("Start");
    stop = new JButton("Stop");
    speed = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 2, 1);
    playerList = new JComboBox(getPlayerStyle());

    // Slider label
    Hashtable labelTable = new Hashtable();
    labelTable.put(new Integer(0), new JLabel("Slow"));
    labelTable.put(new Integer(1), new JLabel("Normal"));
    labelTable.put(new Integer(2), new JLabel("Fast"));
    speed.setLabelTable(labelTable);
    speed.setPaintLabels(true);

    // Combo box dropdown
    playerList.setSelectedIndex(1);

    // Timer
    tim = new Timer(getDelay(), this);

    // Add methods
    add(start);
    add(stop);
    add(timer);
    add(speed);
    add(score);
    add(playerList);

    // Event listeners
    start.addActionListener(this);
    stop.addActionListener(this);
    speed.addChangeListener(this);
    playerList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
            String playerChoice = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
            playerList.setSelectedItem(playerChoice);
        }
    });

    // Set focus to false on all game controls
    start.setFocusable(false);
    stop.setFocusable(false);
    speed.setFocusable(false);
    playerList.setFocusable(false);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    Object obj = event.getSource();

    if (obj == getTim()) {
        setI(getI() + 1);
        getTimer().setText("Timer: " + getI());
        getScore().setText("Field Goals: " + getCurrentScore() + "       Tackles: " + getCurrentTackles());
    }
    if (obj == getStop()) {
        getTim().stop();
    }
    if (obj == getStart()) {
        getTim().start();
    }
}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    JSlider source = (JSlider) e.getSource();

    int currentSpeed = (int) source.getValue();
    if (currentSpeed == 0) {
        int delaySpeed = getTim().getDelay();
        delaySpeed = (int) 2000;
        getTim().setDelay(delaySpeed);
    }
    if (currentSpeed == 1) {
        int delaySpeed = getTim().getDelay();
        delaySpeed = (int) 1000;
        getTim().setDelay(delaySpeed);
    }
    if (currentSpeed == 2) {
        int delaySpeed = getTim().getDelay();
        delaySpeed = (int) 500;
        getTim().setDelay(delaySpeed);
    }

}
```

**MyJPanel.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyJPanel extends JPanel {

public MyJPanel() {
    super();
    setBackground(Color.gray);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    ControlPanel gm = new ControlPanel();
    GameField gf = new GameField();
    add(gm, "North");
    add(gf, "Center");
}
```

}

Comment: One thing you can do is add some print statements (`System.out.println()`) to your code which will tell you **what** is happening.  "Nothing happens" doesn't help us much.  Do some debugging and tell us at what point what you expect to happen diverges from what you see happening.

Comment: Thanks mark, I will post back on what I find. Most appreciated!

Comment: you can also run your program in debug mode and put breakpoints around

Comment: You said "when calling methods on the control panel from the game field panel, nothing happens" but I don't see any code that invokes methods on the control panel unless you're saying methods like `setTackle1PositionX` and `getTackle1PositionX` are calling methods on the control panel. I don't think you've share enough of the relevant code, could you please show how control panel is invoked? You should probably also show how the game field gets its reference to the control panel.

Comment: Side note: classes should begin with capital letter, see [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: @D.B. Thanks for the information. I've corrected the naming conventions by reading the documentation. I've also added additional information on this issue. Thanks for taking the time on reading this!

Comment: Looking at your updates I suspect it has to do with the fact your GameField creates a new ControlPanel rather than using an existing reference. I think you should debug from this perspective and see where it goes.

Comment: You've posted an awful lot of code here, and I'm struggling to understand how your description relates to it. You might find that you get better answers if you can reduce the code you've posted to the specific, relevant parts, with more detail around what you expect to happen and what you're actually observing, with references to the code you've posted. I'm a bit lost in all the background about American Football! :)

Comment: @D.B. I can't believe I've been ripping my hair out on this. I think I might know what I've been doing all wrong. Thanks for the friendly nudge!

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave Yes, I apologize for this atrocious post! This is my very first post and I've really destroyed it :(. I also should have mentioned it was "American" Football, as a respect to "Real" Football :)

Comment: Haha, don't be too harsh on yourself - more information is definitely better than less, and as for the code being "awful," it's significantly better than many so-called professional developers I've worked with who have years of experience!

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave thanks for that Dave! I’ve heard a lot of stigma around the community here, but you really changed my perspective and motivated me to work harder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @D.B. I have gotten my code to run as intended. Because I only intend to have two JPanels (Control Panel and Game Panel), I added the panels to pass as arguments to each other. After this, the code started working as intended. Thank you for pushing me into the right step! It was such a simple mistake. Special thanks to @DaveyDaveDave for motivating me to push harder!

Changes I made to my main JPanel object:

```
public class MyJPanel extends JPanel {

    ControlPanel gm = new ControlPanel();
    GameField gf = new GameField();

    public MyJPanel() {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.gray);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(gm, "North");
        add(gf, "Center");

        gf.setCp(gm);
        gm.setGf(gf);
    }
}
```